# why is the app required to exit twice after unexpected destroy?

Tags: android

When my app is in background, I use third part manager to close the app's progress.Then I exit the app at first, but it will reopen automatically. What's the possible reason?

This is my exit code:

```
for (Activity activity : mActivityList) {
        activity.finish();
    }
    System.exit(0);
```

Comment: grammar improvement.

Comment: Quite simply, you should not be using a "third part manager to close the app's progress" as Android is not design to work that way, and may *actively* combat such efforts by re-launching the process as you have seen.  Don't design apps around the idea of process death, design them in accordance with the **activity lifecycle** which makes that largely irrelevant.

Comment: @ChrisStratton yes,i known.But users may do that... they will realize it's wrong.

Answer (score 0):

`activity.finish();` will finishes the current execute activity only. While `System.exit(0);` will close all the activity along with the application.

However in Android usage of `System.exit(0);` is not advisable. You should simple use `finish();` statement to close all the activity along with the application.

Comment: what code?  above is my exit part code.I tried to remove the "System.exit()" .